# why Express does not implement Node.js style callbacks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, callback, q

I have a question regarding the APIs. Why express does not implement Node.js style callbacks, i.e., ***Error-First Callbacks***?

For example, [router.METHOD](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#router.METHOD):

```
router.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('hello world');
});
```

And furthermore, I also saw this [Error handling](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html):

```
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  // logic
})
```

Then, my question is: after add the *Error Handling* middleware as above, can I regard my code as following?

```
router.get('/', function(err, req, res, next){
  res.send('hello world');
});
```

If so, I am able to use [Q.denodeify](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#qnfbindnodefunc-args) converting the callback style to promise style right? Because `Q.denodeify`, as stated [here](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#interfacing-with-nodejs-callbacks), only deals with *Node.js style `(err, result)` callback APIs*

Comment: What error you are expecting before manipulating API request ?

Comment: @Rayon my first question is: *Why express does not implement Node.js style callbacks, i.e., Error-First Callbacks?* Or I did not understand its implementation?     To answer your question: I would like to migrate my nested callbacks to promises.     But probably you are right, it does not mean I have to start from the very beginning callback of `router.get`.

Comment: There is no possibility of `error` in the handler function of any `API` request...

Comment: @ChangLiu It does not use a node.js-style result callback that is called once simply because it's not a result callback. It's the same reason why `EventEmitter` doesn't use node.js-style callbacks either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An Express route handler can't be represented as a promise, because promises *run once*, whereas route handlers need to be *run many times*.

Express does actually use Node style callbacks whenever appropriate—e.g. `next(err)`.

> Then, my question is: after add the Error Handling middleware as above, can I regard my code as following?

You could, but you'd be defeating the point of error handlers in the first place. In the traditional Express app, when a request fails with an error, the route handlers after it can be safely skipped so that it can be passed to an error handler instead.

If you write all of your routes as error handlers then there's no semantic distinction between the parts of your code that handle success and the parts that handle failure. If a route handler throws or calls `next(err)` then the error will be passed to the next matching application route handler instead of to a dedicated error handler.

As a side note, this is more a question about [Connect](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect), the HTTP middleware implementation that Express is built on.

Comment: *"You could"*: do you mean that, when I do this `Q.denodeify(router.get.bind.(router))`, `Q.denodeify` will regard `router.get` is having the callback like `function(err, req, res, next){...}`?

Comment: No, you can't wrap the router because it isn't a function. You also can't use denodeify with error handlers because it [returns a 0 argument function](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/blob/v1/q.js#L1944-L1950), which [connect will treat as a route handler](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/index.js#L233-L240) because there are less than 4 arguments.

Comment: Take a look at [express-promise-router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-promise-router) if you want an example of what a sensible promise integration looks like for express.

Answer (score 0):

It does, but in this case you are using routers and if you want to handle those errors you should declare error middleware at the end of the file.
There is done() callback which takes first argument err and second done and this is the exact same callback style which node.js uses.